# How to bring existing LaTeX files as chapters of thesis appendix?

Tags: chapters, appendix

I will have two chapters under Appendix as shown in the image below.

[image]

I use `\include{appendices/appendices}` in my overarching LaTeX file to refer to my appendix LaTeX file.

Inside the appendix LaTeX, I have the following:

[image]

I just want to turn those chapters into papers.  I have a complete set of files and a LaTeX file for each of the papers. I would like to bring it straight in but unsure how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this, is using the package 'subfiles'. In your main `.tex`-file, which I will call `thesis.tex`, you use something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{Conclusions and Outlook}
    \lipsum[1-5]

    \subfile{appendices/appendices}
    % Revert graphicspath to normal (it is modified in appendices.tex)
    \graphicspath{{./}}
\end{document}
```

then in `appendices/appendices.tex` you have something like this:

```
% The 'magic' comment below allows you to compile the appendices.tex on itself.
% Else, your editor might always compile the thesis.tex instead.
% !TeX root=appendices.tex

\documentclass[../../thesis]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
    \graphicspath{{appendices/images/}}
    \appendix
    \chapter{Paper 1}
    \lipsum[6-8]

    \chapter{Paper 2}
    \lipsum[9-11]
\end{document}
```

Automatically, all definitions you make in the preamble of `thesis.tex` will be available in your `appendices.tex`.

Has this answer helped you? :)